# How to integrate guru with visual studio code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-guru

I followed the [guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/edit), and 
I have it installed on my linux system: `guru -help` works.

And at the point of integrating it with `vs-code` the guide says consult it at:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go

but I don't see how. Any step-by-step guides or anything that would help me?

Thank you